# How to calculate distance in location app in qt mobility (symbian)?

Tags: qt, geolocation, qt-mobility

How can I calculate distance in QT by geocoordinates given by Qgeopositioninfo ?
How can I fetch 2 coordinates: now and previous, and calculate? My trouble is: how to fetch 2 coordinates: which is given now, and which was given previous, and after calculating set now as previous ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGeoCoordinate::distanceTo(QGeoCoordinate) that returns a value in meters.

```
distance = previous.distanceTo(now);
```